# Sending push notifications from a webview app

Tags: java, php, android, webview

I'm working on a responsive website which I will then integrate in an Android webview to build an app. This website is a kind of social network with a built-in notification system.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to send push notifications from the built-in notification system of my website into the right user's phone. I have already built native Android apps and have included some push notification systems... But it was a native app, so I was able to catch the Android device ID to identify the user. In this case, I have a responsive website (into a webview app) where the user logs in / register with HTML, jQuery, PHP languages, not Java. So I'm not able to get the Android device ID.

I had an idea to do that but I'm not sure if it's the best one, so please correct me if I'm wrong :

1. The user starts my app on his phone
2. If it's the first time he launches it, we send a request to my
   server with the Android device ID + IP address of the user that I store in the DB (in Java language to my server, before starting the webview)
3. The webview starts
4. The user creates an account and I check on my website if an entry exists in the DB which matches the user's IP address. If that's the case, I can create a new entry in my DB with the new created user ID and his device ID. Then, it's easy to send him push notifications.

I think it's maybe a little difficult as a solution, but what do you think about it ? Or do you have some suggestions to help me to achieve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well an IP address is a transient thing, so i doubt thats a great idea

Comment: @Steve I agree. That's why I'm asking if there would be another better solution because I'm aware mine is not the best!